# Find & delete folder (ubuntu server)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, find, backup

I have a backup system in my ubuntu server that every day makes a database backup and save it in a folder named like the day: $(date +%d%m%y)
But on the script, when I try to find and delete the folders from the last week, the command don't find any directory.

Im trying with: find -name $(date +%d%m%y) -type d -mtime +7 -exec rm -r {};
And never find a directory. Y tryed changing the -mtime time to 1 day or 2, but dont find nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a small mistake:

When you backup on the 7th of may, you create a folder with name 070515. When you search a week later, you look for a folder with name 140515 modified more then 7 days ago. However, this folder has been created only today.

You may not need the name of the folder, just use

```
find /backup/path -type d -mtime +7
```

to find all folders older then 7 days.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect at least two errors in your `find` command:

1. The path is missing where to search: `find /where/to/search -name ...`
2. `$(date +%d%m%y)` always gives the actual date. It looks reasonable that directories with actual date don't have a modification time +1 or +7. Instead try following:

   ```
   find /where/to/search -type d -mtime +7
   ```